# JPA: flexibly mapping "attributes" (key/value data of various data types) to an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm having some issues deciding how to map key/value data to an entity in a sensible and performant way. I might even be taking a wrong approach here, so I'm thankful for any hints.

Basically, this is about associating various common attributes with a a real estate property entity, for example:

- elevator: yes/no (boolean)
- bedrooms: 2 (integer)
- furnishing: [full | partial | none] ("enum")
- view: free-form text (string)

The attributes and their data type (string, bool, integer, "enum" - one out of a number of pre-defined strings) should be defined at runtime, i.e. be stored in the database. An attribute type might also contain metadata for generating a GUI (min/max/stepping for int, etc). Also, it should be possible to efficiently query for any set of key/value combinations, i.e. an apartment with more than 2 bedrooms, unfurnished, with an elevator.

I started my approach with joined inheritance (simplified code):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Attribute
{
    @Id
    public int attribute_id;
    public String name;
    public int type;
}
```

and a derived class for each kind of attribute:

```
@Entity
public class IntAttribute extends Attribute
{
    public int minvalue;
    public int maxvalue;
    public int stepping;
}

@Entity
public class EnumAttribute extends Attribute
{
    @OneToMany(...)
    public List<EnumAttributeValue> values = new ArrayList<EnumAttributeValue>();
}
```

I soon hit a wall with this approach since EnumAttribute doesn't have any properties on its own apart from a list of possible values, meaning that I would probably have an enum_attribute table containing only an attribute_id and nothing else. Same with StringAttribute and BooleanAttribute, which don't have any properties that aren't already in the Attribute base class.

I'm also not quite sure how I'd map the actual key/value pair to an entity. Create an AttributeValue base class and one for each data type? Try doing a flat TABLE_PER_CLASS hierarchy for the actual values for efficient searching?

I must admit, I'm fresh out of ideas. I'm aware that a document-oriented database like MongoDB would be a better fit, but sadly this isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: Great question. I would be interested to see, what your solution was. Iam currently thinking also about ways to solve this problem.